# Bootstrap v4 runtime/load error in Aurelia

Tags: javascript, aurelia, bootstrap-4

I have the following in my `aurelia.json` file, among the rest of what you'd usually find. I copied it directly from the reference implementation, and as you'd therefore expect, it works fine.

```
{
  'build': {
    'bundles': [
      'name': 'vendor-bundle.js'
      'dependencies': [
        "jquery",
        {
          "name": "bootstrap",
          "path": "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist",
          "main": "js/bootstrap.min",
          "deps": ["jquery"],
          "exports": "$",
          "resources": [
            "css/bootstrap.css"
          ]
        }
      ]
    ]
  }
}
```

However, I'm trying to migrate to Bootstrap 4, and it just doesn't seem to be working. In order to update the package, I've tried changing `build.bundles.dependencies[].path` to `../jspm_packages/github/twbs/bootstrap@4.0.0-beta` as well as to `../node_modules/bootstrap-v4-dev/dist`, but it doesn't change the error code or make the error manifest any less. I've also tried copying the v4 files into the dist folder for v3, which also causes the same problem.

Build is always clean; the error occurs at run-time:

```
DEBUG [templating] importing resources for app.html
Uncaught TypeError: plugin.load is not a function
Unhandled rejection Error: Failed loading required CSS file: bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css
```

EDIT:

Thanks to Ashley Grant's answer, I have updated Bootstrap through NPM, obviating any changes to `aurelia.json`. The error remains unchanged, which would seem to indicate a bug were it not for the fact that other people have successfully performed this migration without errors using the same toolchain.

EDIT2:

I've created steps to reproduce the bug:

```
$ au new
name  # can be any valid value
2     # Selects TypeScript as the language
1     # Create project structure
1     # Install dependencies
```

`cd` into the project directory.

Add the two entries listed above to `build.bundles[1].dependencies` in `aurelia_project/aurelia.json`

```
$ npm install jquery --save
$ npm install bootstrap@^4.0.0-beta --save
```

Change `src/app.html` to the following:

```
<template>
  <require from="bootstrap/css/bootstrap.css"></require>
</template>
```

Finally, execute either of the following and browse to the provided URL.

```
$ au run
```

OR

```
$ au build
$ serve
```

This yields the errors described in both `Google Chrome Version 55.0.2883.87 (64-bit)` and `Mozilla Firefox 55.0.3` on my Arch Linux systems. I've not yet had the opportunity to test it on other systems.

Edit3:

Thanks to @vidriduch, everything appears to be working. However, if you look at the console, you find the following:

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token export
vendor-bundle.js:3927Uncaught Error: Mismatched anonymous define() module: [entirety of vendor-bundle.js printed here]
```

These are the two very first messages when the page loads in debug mode, but no other errors arise.

Comment: try to use full version of bootstrap -> "main": "js/bootstrap.js" although I dont see connection there ...

Comment: This produced no change.

Comment: I've also tried removing the `.js` extension found in your suggestion, and doing so also failed to produce any change.

Comment: what about the popper dependency for bootstrap 4 beta? It has to be installed separatelly and add "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js" to prepend part of vendor-bundle

Comment: Thank  you! This made the original error go away and allowed the screen to render in the intended way, but I'm getting a new error. See edit for details.

Comment: you need to install version 1.11.0 for popper; npm install popper.js@1.11.0

Comment: Unfortuantely, downgrading to 1.11.0 made no difference in either the compiler output or the console.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are missing popper.js dependency for Bootstrap 4.0.0-beta.
In order for Aurelia to accept this add

```
 "node_modules/popper.js/dist/umd/popper.js"
```

on the top (as per comment from @hxtk) of *prepend* part of *aurelia.json* (assuming that you are using RequireJS, otherwise have a look at webpack dependency linking for Bootstrap https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/getting-started/webpack/)

Just to mention, the version of popper.js you need to install is *1.11.0* (https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/issues/23381), so

```
npm install popper.js@1.11.0
```

or

```
yarn add popper.js@1.11.0
```

and it should work :)

Comment: I've accepted this as the correct answer because it makes the application initially render properly. However, dropdown menus still do not work, among the little that I've tested. Note, in the same browser they've been confirmed to work in a known good Bootstrap v4 environment.

Comment: @hxtk the aurelia part should be ok now. trhy to have a look here https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/migration/ for specific changes when migration to bootstrap 4. I hope they will drop popper, just for simplicity sake. good luck!

Comment: Thank you. I found what the error was: `popper.js` has to be the very first thing in the `prepend` section.

Answer (score 2):

Your `aurelia.json` configuration is correct. I'm going to guess you never ran `npm install bootstrap@^4.0.0-beta --save` as you are mentioning copying files in to a versioned `node_modules` folder, and NPM doesn't use versioned folders like JSPM does.

So run `npm install bootstrap@^4.0.0-beta --save` and things should start working. I have your exact configuration working in an application for one of my clients.

Comment: Thank you. You're correct that I hadn't run that code yet—I should've checked on specifying a version in npm. However, running that did not seem to fix the problem.